# Works with NDSolve, not DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

EDIT1:

```
Clear["`.*"];
    a = 1; ri = 1; thi = 0; zi = 0.; phi = 0.; smax = 12; sii = 
     Pi/3.; slp = .8;
    smallCirc = {(SI'[s] + Sin[PH[s]] Sin[SI[s]]/R[s]) == 
        slp (Cos[PH[s]]/R[s]),
       PH'[s] == -Cos[SI[s]]/a, R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]],
       TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], Z'[s] == Cos[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]],
       R[0] == ri, TH[0] == 0., Z[0] == 0, SI[0] == sii, PH[0] == phi};
    NDSolve[smallCirc, {SI, PH, R, TH, Z}, {s, 0, smax}];
    {si[t_], ph[t_], r[t_], th[t_], 
       z[t_]} = {SI[t], PH[t], R[t], TH[t], Z[t]} /. First[%];
    Plot[{si[s], ph[s], r[s], th[s], z[s]}, {s, 0, smax}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic]
    sor = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] + v], r[s] Sin[th[s] + v], 
        z[s]}, {s, 0, smax}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> SPH, 
       PlotStyle -> Blue] ;
    fila = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] + 0], r[s] Sin[th[s] + 0], 
        z[s]}, {s, 0, smax}, PlotLabel -> 3 _D Projn, 
       PlotStyle -> {Thick,White}];
    smll = Show[{sor, fila}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None, 
      Boxed -> False, PlotLabel -> "SMLL_CIRCS_ SPH"]
    soln = DSolve[smallCirc, {SI, PH, R, TH, Z}, s]
```

[image]

The above tries to compute small circle (runs between equator/ smaller parallel circle) on sphere with four integrated parameters *{angle to meridian,meridian to axis  and polar coordinates}*. While it works with an NDSolve (to obtain above picture extra Z is included) , it does not compute as a function of arc length $s$ with the analytical solution DSolve in a required closed form. What do I miss? Thanks for help.

Comment: no closed-form solution?

Comment: Remove `Z[0]==0`  !

Comment: What is the actual mathematical problem you are attempting to solve?  Can you provide a reference?

Comment: These are standard expressions for geodesic curvature and meridian coupled ODEs. The image with small circle  shows that it works for NDSolve only

Comment: I get a `Set::write` error when I paste your code and run it.

Comment: What does it mean and how is it fixed? There is a typo in $PH'[s]$ sign but that should n't matter.

Comment: It means I see this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7BKlg.png -- What do you get when you copy the code from the post, paste it, and run it?

Comment: I get nothing.. no diagnostic message at all ( after soln = .. integrand list echo)

Comment: I don't know the basis for your equations, but `DSolve` solves this geodesic equations over the unit sphere: `DSolve[
 {D[θ'[t], t] == -Cos[θ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] ϕ'[t], ϕ'[t] Cos[θ[t]]^2 == C[1]} // Simplify, {θ, ϕ}, t]` -- You could try posting one command per line. Usually it's a missing semicolon somehwere.

Comment: Thank you. Code changed each parameter replacement rather than group Evaluate. ( somehow I am more comfortable with it to track). Also lines separated lines as you suggested.

Comment: You have changed `PH'[s] == -Cos[SI[s]]/a` to include a minus sign, which changes the `NDSolve` solution significantly.  Is that correct?  Also, can you relate your variables to the usual spherical coordinate variables for geodesic equations?

Comment: Programming for constant $\kappa_g$ which are *not geodesics*, they are displaced small circles. About minus sign at first I was checking *Mathematica* solvability for closed form here at all.

Comment: Setting slp=0 gives special case of geodesics.

Answer (score 1):

`DSolve` doesn't find a closed form solution!

Remove `Z[0]==0` (misplaced initial condition!). Now `NDSolve` finds a solution

```
a = 1; ri = 1; thi = 0; zi = 0.; phi = 0.; sii =Pi/3.; slp = .8

smllCirc = {(SI'[s] + Sin[PH[s]] Sin[SI[s]]/R[s]) == slp (Cos[PH[s]]/R[s]), PH'[s] == Cos[SI[s]]/a,R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]],TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s],R[0] == ri , TH[0] == 0., SI[0] == sii, PH[0] == phi}

sol = NDSolveValue[smllCirc, {SI, PH, R, TH}, {s, 0, 1}]
Plot[Through[sol[x]], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Vielen Dank! But it does not work (presumably due to my earlier Ver 8.0 ), even after removing ( misplaced  Z[0]==0.) !  Secondly I did not expect that *Mathematica* cannot capture these standard trigonometric circular functions in closed form...

Comment: If you increase the simulation range you'll see that the result is more than standard trigonometrical.

Comment: @Narasimham  It is, however, possible to obtain `SI` and `R` symbolically in terms of `PH`, and perhaps more.  I shall try to find time to write it up tomorrow.